# wget web crawler retrieves unwanted index.html index files

Tags: command-line, wget

I made a `~/.bashrc` function to save some web directories into my local disk. It works well except some unwanted index files that is not present in the website.
I use it like

```
crwl http://ioccc.org/2013/cable3/
```

but it also retrieves some files such as `index.html?C=D;O=A index.html?C=D;O=D index.html?C=M;O=A index.html?C=M;O=D index.html?C=N;O=A index.html?C=N;O=D index.html?C=S;O=A index.html?C=S;O=D`

Complete file list:

```
 kenn@kenn:~/experiment/crwl/ioccc.org/2013/cable3$ ls
 bios        index.html?C=D;O=A  index.html?C=S;O=A           screenshot_flightsim4.png
 cable3.c    index.html?C=D;O=D  index.html?C=S;O=D           screenshot_lotus123.png
 fd.img      index.html?C=M;O=A  Makefile                     screenshot_qbasic.png
 hint.html   index.html?C=M;O=D  runme                        screenshot_simcity.png
 hint.text   index.html?C=N;O=A  sc-ioccc.terminal            screenshot_win3_on_macosx.png
 index.html  index.html?C=N;O=D  screenshot_autocad.png
```

I want to exclude those files while cloning that directory with `wget` 
Is there any `wget` switch or trick to clone a web directory as it is?

My script function in `.bashrc`:

```
crwl() {
wget --tries=inf --timestamping --recursive --level=inf --convert-links --page-requisites --no-parent "$@"

}
```

EDIT: I found two possible workarounds

1) Adding `-R index.html?*` flag

2) Adding `-R =A,=D` flag
which rejects   `index.html?C=D;O=A` files except `index.html`

I don't know which one is proper but both of them seem unsafe.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by safety, in: `I don't know which one is proper but both of them seem unsafe.`

Comment: @user454038
I mean it may reject some files with `index.html?*`  which is essential part of retrieved files. I don't understand usage of `index.html?C=D;O=A` files. There might be more precise rule to exclude those files.

Answer (score 7):

To exclude index-sort files such as those with URL `index.html?C=...` without excluding any other kind of `index.html*` files, there is indeed a more precise specification possible. Try: `-R '\?C='`

### Quick Demo

Set up an different empty directory, for example

```
$ mkdir ~/experiment2
$ cd ~/experiment2
```

Then a shorter version of your command, without the recursion and levels in order to do a quick one page test:

```
$ wget --tries=inf --timestamping --convert-links --page-requisites --no-parent -R '\?C=' http://ioccc.org/2013/cable3/
```

After wget is done, `~/experiment2`, will have no `index.html?C=...` files:

```
.
└── ioccc.org
    ├── 2013
    │   └── cable3
    │       └── index.html
    ├── icons
    │   ├── back.gif
    │   ├── blank.gif
    │   ├── image2.gif
    │   ├── text.gif
    │   └── unknown.gif
    └── robots.txt

4 directories, 7 files
```

So it has indeed excluded those redundant index-sort `index.html?C=...` directories while keeping all other index.html directories, in this case just `index.html`

### Implement

So just implement the `-R '\?C='` , by updating your shell function in `~/.bashrc`:

```
crwl() {
  wget --tries=inf --timestamping --recursive --level=inf --convert-links --page-requisites --no-parent -R '\?C=' "$@"
}
```

Then remember to either test in a new terminal, or re-source bash to make it effective:

```
$ . ~/.bashrc
```

Then try it in a new directory, for comparison:

```
$ mkdir ~/experiment3
$ cd ~/experiment3
$ crwl http://ioccc.org/2013/cable3/
```

### Warranty

- wget 1.14 and up only. So if your `wget -V` says it is 1.13 this may not work and you have need to actually delete those pesky `index.html?C=...` yourself, or try to get a more recent version of wget.
- works by specifying you want to `-R` or reject a pattern, in this case pages with `?C=` pattern that is typical of the `index.html?C=...` versions of `index.html`.
- however `?` happens to be a wget wildcard, thus to match a literal `?` you need to escape it as `\?`
- don't interrupt wget. Because it seems the way wget works with browse-able web pages is to actually download first, delete later, as if it needs to check in case those pages have further links to crawl. So if you cancel this halfway you are still going to end up with `index.html?C=` files. Only if you let wget finish, then wget will follow your `-R` specification and delete any temporarily downloaded `index.html?C=...` files for you

Answer (score 2):

Try this after download, if you do not want to use wget's removal mechanism or are on a system not suporting this option.

```
FIND=$($WHICH find)
PWD2=$($WHICH pwd)
SH=$($WHICH sh)
ECHO=$($WHICH echo)
LESS=$($WHICH less)
```

Command:

```
$FIND "$($PWD2)" -regextype posix-egrep -type f -regex '^(.*?html\?C=[DNSM];O=[AD])$' -exec "$SH" -c 'o="{}";$ECHO -f -v "${o}"' \; | $LESS
```

When you are satisfied with the output, do the following:

1. Issue the following command (see below box)
2. Replace $ECHO with $RM in the above command.
3. Remove the pipe (|) and the $LESS, to get actual output.

**(I'm not responsible for when you delete your whole file system, therefore this way.)**

```
RM=$($WHICH rm);export RM
$FIND "$($PWD2)" -regextype ... ;$RM -f -v "${xox}"' \;
```

Hope this helps.